# Create simple SQL database with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, local

I's struggling to get my hands around a database and It seems that every programmer had it's own way of doing it.

I need very simple database that is stored locally and could eventually be moved into a server without much effort. Also I don't want design the database manually as this suppose to only reflect the data used in my program. So I decided to try LINQ with automatic mapping but I have a problem.

**This is what I've done:**

1. Create new WPF project.
2. Add new Service-Based-Database item named `myDB`.
3. Write following code:

   ```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window {
       public MainWindow() {
           InitializeComponent();

           var dc = new DataContext("myDB.mdf");
           var dt = dc.GetTable<SimpleData>();
           var ds = from d in dt select d;
           foreach (var d in ds) {
               Debug.WriteLine($"{d.number} : {d.text}");
           }
       }
    }

    [Table]
    public class SimpleData {
       [Column]
       public int number { get; set; } = 10;
       [Column]
       public string text { get; set; } = "hello";

       public SimpleData() { }
    }
   ```

Now at the `foreach` loop I have an **exception:**

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file myDB.mdf failed.
>   A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

**What is missing?**

Comment: You should pass the `ConnectionString` to your `DataContext` instead of your database name!

Comment: An mdf file is the output file from a SQL Sever Management Studio and you need SSMS installed on the computer to generate the database.  MySQL output file is a file with the sdf extension.

Comment: I've seen couple examples were only file name is specified and the constructor's documentation says "This argument can be any one of the following: The name of a file where a SQL Server Express database resides.

The name of a server where a database is present. In this case the provider uses the default database for a user.

A complete connection string. LINQ to SQL just passes the string to the provider without modification."

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I think the name that you've seen, is the name of the `ConnectionString` node that is declared already in the config file, not the name of the database.

Comment: @jdweng So if VS generated mdf for me I must have SSMS installed already? If the file is not a database, how do I create it?  I've seen they are specifying path to mdf file here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/walkthrough-simple-object-model-and-query-csharp#specifying-the-connection-to-the-northwind-database

Comment: What is the database name?  is it myDB or myDB.mdf?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just only did the 3 steps I described in the question, nothing else. I can browse tables of the files in Server Explorer but there are no tables created.